# how to make a faded Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How does one make a navigation bar that fades out? the top having an alpha of say 0.5, with the bottom half being 0.  As it goes from top to bottom, the alpha decreases and it becomes more transparent.

Something like this:  [image]

As you can see, it becomes more transparent as you go down the nav bar.

Comment: what you tried for, please explain more about your ques.

Comment: @vaibhav sorry?

Comment: @luke Post what you've tried first. The public will not want to type the code for you. Show eventual troubles you are having and you are likely to get good answer. That's what vaibhav wanted to say.

Comment: @pedrouan I guess, although I don't have much code to show for it.  I've edited my question to show exactly what I'm trying to achieve. I can't say much apart from saying I've tried to set the nav bar to x colour and y alpha.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use **`CAGradientLayer`** for this purpose. I've tested and works.
For ***Swift 3.0***.

```
let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

// put colors into an array, from top to bottom
gradient.colors = [UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor]
gradient.frame = view.frame

// setting direction and stop points - from top to bottom
gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)

yourView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
```